# symfony doctrine getArrayResult error 500

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity

I'm trying to grab some data from an table which works fine as long as I don't use

```
->andwhere('s.client_id = :clientid')
->setParameter('clientid', $this->clientId)
```

I f use the two line above to locate only neccessary data, I end up in a error 500 :(:(

The entity looks like:

```
class SanitationType
{
/**
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
*/
protected $id;


/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Pr\UserBundle\Entity\Client")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $client;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20)
 * @Gedmo\Translatable
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 * @Gedmo\Translatable
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="`enabled`", type="boolean")
 */
private $enabled;
    /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $created_by;
    /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $created;

..............
```

and my script to grab the data inside the controller looks like this:

```
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('s')
    ->from('PrSensorBundle:SanitationType', 's')
    ->where('s.enabled = 1')
    ->andwhere('s.client_id = :client_id')
    ->setParameter('client_id', $this->clientId)
    ->orderBy('s.name', 'ASC')
    ->getQuery();
$results=$query->getArrayResult();
```

I don't see any error but it is not working at all :(:(

Do I forgot something?

Comment: Have you tried this same call with `app_dev.php`? What about the web server error logs? Have you tried wrapping the call in a `try..catch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things. First, it's not clear what `$this->clientId` refers to, but if you're trying to reference the id of the client object associated with a SanitationType object, then you'd need to have a public `getClient()` method on the SanitationType class and a `getId()` method on the Client class. So obtaining the client id from a SanitationType object `$sanitationType` then becomes:

```
$sanitationType->getClient()->getId()
```

Second, there is no `client_id` property in the SanitationType class. Doctrine sees the properties of a class as you've defined them. So in this case, to look up a SanitationType object(s) in the database by the id of a Client association(s), you would need to perform an inner join. Your query builder would look like this:

```
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('s')
    ->from('PrSensorBundle:SanitationType', 's')
    ->innerJoin('s.client', 'sc')
    ->where('s.enabled = 1')
    ->andwhere('sc.id = :client_id')
    ->setParameter('client_id', $this->clientId)
    ->orderBy('s.name', 'ASC')
    ->getQuery();
$results=$query->getArrayResult();
```

Comment: OMG, you are right. There is really no client_id :( I just looked in the db itself, no in the entity. Whene using "client" instead of "client_id" it works well.... Sorry for my negligence and thank you two for your help.